# Insert value of link into $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller with a $scope in it,

```
$scope.value = "5v8uEFkzwAY"
```

In my app I have a few `a` link elements with a value, I want to store that value into the `$scope.value` on a click function.

```
<a href="#" value="KlyknsTJk0w">On click insert this value into $scope.value</a>
<a href="#" value="nyc6RJEEe0U">On click insert this value into $scope.value</a>
<a href="#" value="zSWdZVtXT7E">On click insert this value into $scope.value</a>
<a href="#" value="Lm8p5rlrSkY">On click insert this value into $scope.value</a>
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve expected behavior by using the code below:

In your controller:

```
$scope.values = ['KlyknsTJk0w', 'nyc6RJEEe0U', 'zSWdZVtXT7E', 'Lm8p5rlrSkY'];

$scope.value = '5v8uEFkzwAY';

$scope.setValue = function(newValue) {
    $scope.value = newValue;
};
```

In HTML:

```
<a ng-repeat="v in values" href="#" ng-click="setValue(v)">On click insert this value into {{v}}</a>

Selected value: {{value}}
```

Here you got the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arpgz3vm/

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a method solution.

```
 $scope.setValue = function($event){
    $scope.value = $event.target.getAttribute('value')
  }
```

HTML

```
 <a href="#" value="KlyknsTJk0w" ng-click="setValue($event)">On click nsert this value into $scope.value</a>
```

just you can use `inline` code.

```
<a href="#", value="KlyknsTJk0w" ng-click="value = $event.target.getAttribute('value')">On click nsert this value into $scope.value</a>
```

where as value referring to `$scope.value` and this.value referring to anker tags attributes(named as value).

Here is the working plunkr [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rj3dQK5u49mM7NrMb9pG)

Comment: This will not work. `this` is a reference to the scope, not to the clicked element.

Comment: How does `value` refer to `$scope.value` in the controller though? I'm not getting any response from the click.

Comment: if it in inside controller then value refers to current scope.

Comment: The inline code also will not work, you cannot refer to DOM in Angular 1.3+

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is with a directive:

```
module.directive('myClick', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.value = attrs.value;
        scope.$digest();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can use it like here:

```
<a href="#" value="nyc6RJEEe0U" my-click>On click insert this value into $scope.value</a>
```

Comment: This sort of works, but I need to return my value into the controller. So is there a way to traverse the value from the directive into the controller?

Comment: With `scope.value` you are assigning the value into the scope: a `{{value}}` anywhere in the same scope would show the value itself.  What do you mean by 'from the directive into the controller'?